# Tag for Sitecore Powershell Extensions?

Tags: discussion

Just saw our first question, tagged with 'sitecorepowershell'.

What should be the tag used in this community for questions related to powershell?

- sitecore-powershell-extensions
- powershell
- SPE
- Other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to propose using `powershell-extensions`.

Using `powershell` alone may lead to confusion with "[Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info)", especially when talking about automation of Sitecore Deployments. I understand that we're on a Sitecore specific SE site now, but that doesn't mean that none of the normal Windows and .Net frameworks do not the apply and there may be relevant questions that cross all those boundaries.

We can use synonyms to cover the other use cases.

Comment: +1 I was going to make the same point

Answer (score 3):

I'd say SPE. It's the acronym it's known under, and also how the authors themselves refer to it.

I'd avoid spelliing out "sitecore-powershell-extensions" since we're now on a Sitecore specific Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually go with `powershell`. It's obviously going to be about SPE in the context of this site.

We can then set SPE as a known synonym for the tag. It basically means, SE will autocorrect people tagging SPE to "powershell". Can add a few more to the mix if and when we need - the important thing is to just get the "real" tag right, the way we want it.

[image: Synonym Description]

So in this example here; I propose we re-tag it "powershell" and then add SPE as a synonym.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the synonym, which renders my editing point moot. Good shout.

Comment: No, not moot. There can be a million permutations, and we can't synonym them all ;-)   Nor should we, I guess.  But the ones that are valid and commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer powershell.

SPE is the abbreviated form of the module name, but I'm not sure it's quite at the level of say, WFFM, in its recognisability (yet!).

Additionally, I think members are more likely to start typing in pow- and find the powershell tag, rather than type SPE. So if we standardised on SPE it would like result in more editing required to keep the tagging correct too.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with powershell as well and set it as synonym for SPE as suggested